# How do you register Qt QML Singleton's that depend on each other?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am building a Qt application using some C++ and some JavaScript/QML.

I have three global singletons, A, B, and C, that I want to register with the QML Engine.  I can register each object independently, using [this method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType).

A, B, and C need to have access to the QMLEngine that is passed to the singleton provider.

Now imagine that B and C depend on A; in particular, the global instance of A needs to be passed into the constructor for B and C.  How can I instantiate and register these types?

Comment: Have you considered a design that does *not* use the singleton anti-pattern?

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes; in this case A, B, and C represent hardware resources which truly are singletons.

Comment: Use lazy initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone who got stung by that really bad, I strongly recommend to not go there, turn back while you still can.

[Qt had a bug with inter-referencing singletons that unfortunately was only partially solved, and it doesn't look like it will get resolved any time soon.](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64934)

The bug causes the QML engine loading to occasionally (10-20% of the time) fail silently, no errors, no warnings, no application window... no nothing. Just a stuck dead process.

If possible, implement A, B and C as sub-objects of one singleton. You can then still expose them individually as properties of the singleton.

Comment: Thanks @dtech; I am very glad to know about this.  Could you link to the bug ticket for reference?  At the moment, I am doing as you say---exposing each sub-object as a property of a single singleton.  It is ugly but it works.